# How to get value after multiple loop iterations

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I have a dictionary and I want a user to input a dictionary key and random float value, then those two are multiplied and the result is stored in a variable. The loop iterates for desired number of times and finally it prints the final value which is a sum of the result of every loop.
This is my code:

```
dic = {"key1":340, "key2":110, "key3":337, "key4":319, "key5":42}
initial_val = 0

for keys in dic:
    value = str(input("insert key value"))
    if value == "key1":
        amount = float(input("enter amount"))
        product=dic.get("key1")*amount
    elif value == "key2":
        amount = float(input("enter amount"))
        product=dic.get("key2")*amount
    elif value == "key3":
        amount = float(input("enter amount"))
        product=dic.get("key3")*amount
    elif value == "key4":
        amount = float(input("enter amount"))
        product=dic.get("key4")*amount
    elif value == "key5":
        amount = float(input("enter amount"))
        product=dic.get("key5")*amount
    elif value==None:
        product=0

    initial_val+= product

    if value=="end":
        break

print(initial_val)
```

The problem is that the code prints a value which is the sum of desired result + last iteration. I assume

```
 print (initial_val)
```

takes

```
initial_val += product
```

and sums it again to the final result.

What is the cause of the problem and how can I solve this?

Comment: initialize `product=0` after `value = str(input("insert key value"))`

Comment: Gaurain Jain, it's a mistake of mine - I did not mean 'desired'; times depend just on dic values, as it should be

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is this:

```
dic = {"key1":340, "key2":110, "key3":337, "key4":319, "key5":42}
initial_val = 0

while True:
    value = str(input("insert key value"))
    if value == "end":  # Break before you make the product !
        break
    amount = float(input("insert amount"))
    product = amount * dic.get(value)  # Make the product if it's not the end
    initial_val += product  # Make the sum

print(initial_val)
```

Because in your case, you waited until the end of the loop to test if `value == "end"`. But if `value` was equal to `"end"`, you would not need to make the product because there is no product to make!

Comment: Thank you for the simplified code and explanation :) but I am still not sure if I understand how putting    `break` to the start of the code fixes the problem.Assume the code is original and let say we have had one loop and after it the initial_val=340. Then another loop adds 340 to the initial_val as the product and now initial_val=680 and only THEN the program asks for input?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really understand what you mean... What you want is just to increase `initial_val` by the product of `dic[value] * amount` every time you ask for a new `value`. And if `value` equals `"end"`, you want to finish the program by quitting the loop, hence the `break`.

Comment: I mean, why the code won't work as desired with the `break` statement at the end of the code(if `value` equals `"end"`)? I truly do not understand the difference in `break` written in the start of the code versus `break` written in the end of it.

Comment: Because if you enter `"end"`, it's not a key of `dic` (`dic["end"]` does not exist). If you wait until the end of the code to make the `break`, it will keep the former value of `product` from the former loop step (because there is no `if` case for `"end"`) which is not what you want.

Comment: That makes sense but this applies for the rectified code you have written. But what about the case of the OP code? `value` in it is not required to be a key of `dic` and there is `if` statement when `value="end"`

Comment: Yes, you're right. But your `if value == "end"` appears after `initial_val += product`. So in your post, you quit the loop after adding a wrong value of `product`. That's the part that is wrong. My answer provides also good techniques to use when to write clean python code for your information :)

Comment: And finally, could you explain how that wrong value of `product` is produced? This is the most confusing part, unfortunately.

Comment: You change `product` every time you have `product = `. When `value` is equal to `"end"`, there has been no `product = ` that has been run. So the value of `product` is the same as the loop before.

Answer (score 0):

```
elif value==None or value == "end":
    product=0
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Move 'if value=="end"' to the start of the code. In that way it would exit the loop before adding it again.